# OpenCV do not want to stop video recording with cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY

Tags: python-3.x, windows, opencv

### when i run this code:

```
from cv2 import *
```

```
image = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
fourcc_cod = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
name = input()
video = cv2.VideoWriter(f"{name}.AVI",fourcc_cod,60,(640,480))
while (True):
    check,frame = image.read()
    frame1 = cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    video.write(frame1)
    cv2.imshow('myimage',frame1)
    if waitKey(1) ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
image.release()
```

it does not stop recording the video Even if I press "q"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
name = input()
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(f'{name}.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
    # uncomment belove line for grayscale
    # frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # write the flipped frame
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release() # video file writer
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: this does not solve the problem because I want video in black and white

Comment: You can simply add this: `frame = cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: but when I added this code to the program, It does not make the video.

Comment: @mohmmedelgamal, When you run the code it asks to write `name` for video file then it will start recording.

Comment: yes, I know this but it made an AVI file but the file did not work